# How to flip the checked status of a Switch only after confirm dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, oncheckedchanged, android-switch

My problem is - when I click on a [`<Switch>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html), it gets toggled first and then the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called.

What I would like is this:

`<Switch>` is clicked --> I show an AlertDialog --> If pressed yes or no --> Then flip ` with [setChecked(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setChecked(boolean)), [boolean = true if pressed yes, and false if pressed no].

**Problem**: When `<Switch>` is clicked, it gets flipped automatically. I want to qualify it with a yes or no from a AlertDialog first.

```
sw_enableDisable
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    getActivity());

                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage(
                                            "Sure you want to enable?. ")
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setPositiveButton(
                                            getString("YES"),
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {

                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            })

                                    .setNegativeButton(
                                            getString("NO"),
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {

                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                            sw_enDis_alreadyClicked = true;

                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    getActivity());
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage(
                                            "Sure you want to disable?")
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setPositiveButton(
                                            getString("YES"),
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {
                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            })

                                    .setNegativeButton(
                                            getString("NO"),
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {

                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code. It worked for me:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    Switch switchButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch_id);

    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Switch btn = (Switch) v;
            final boolean switchChecked = btn.isChecked();

            if (btn.isChecked()) {
                btn.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                btn.setChecked(true);
            }

            String message = "Are you sure you want to disable this setting?";
            if (!btn.isChecked()) {
                message = "Are you sure you want to enable this setting?";
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); // Change "this" to `getActivity()` if you're using this on a fragment
            builder.setMessage(message)
                   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                            // "Yes" button was clicked
                            if (switchChecked) {
                                btn.setChecked(true);
                            } else {
                                btn.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                   .show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work when you slide the switch, onClick event is not triggered. Besides that, what happens on rotation? Do you think that's ok for user experience?

Comment: at least, this is the real accepted answer and solved our problem as well.

Comment: I do not know why this is accepted answer, honestly. If you are hoping to do something very important before checking ( and you probably do, otherwise you wouldn't be asking for confirmation), missing the swipe event is a bug waiting to happen. I suggest handling the swipe of the switch ( or disabling it ), or using another control.

Answer (score 3):

Intercepting touch event will solve the problem. Return TRUE if don't want to send event forward to the system. I came up with below approach.
Have tested, working as expected.

```
switchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (!switchButton.isChecked()) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ActivityLogin.this);

                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage(
                                        "Sure you want to enable?. ")
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("YES",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                switchButton.performClick();
                                            }
                                        })

                                .setNegativeButton(
                                        "NO",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int which) {

                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                        return true;
                    } else{
                        // show dialog Sure you want to disable? and handle the button events accordingly
                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would you be able to add more information as to why this would work, and how it addresses the issues asked in the question? Whilst providing a solution is great, giving the explanation will help others better. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: Intercepting touch event serves our purpose. Simply consume the `ACTION_DOWN` touch event and call `performaClick` to change the switch button status once user done with dialog button events.

Answer (score 2):

prevent switching by setting back state.

```
    Switch switchButton=(Switch)rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch_id);


    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Switch btn=(Switch)v;
            final boolean estado=btn.isChecked();

            if(btn.isChecked())btn.setChecked(false);
            else btn.setChecked(true);


            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if(estado)btn.setChecked(true);
                        else btn.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            String message="Disable function?";
            if(!btn.isChecked()) message="Enable function?";

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("YES", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("NO", dialogClickListener).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following updated code.

```
sw_enableDisable
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        if (toogledProgrammatically) {
                            toogledProgrammatically = false;
                        } else {
                            if (isChecked) {

                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        MainActivity.this);

                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setMessage(
                                                "Sure you want to enable?. ")
                                        .setCancelable(true)
                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                "YES",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                        int which) {

                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                })

                                        .setNegativeButton(
                                                "NO",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                        int which) {

                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                        toogledProgrammatically = true;
                                                        sw_enableDisable.toggle();
                                                    }
                                                });

                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setMessage(
                                                "Sure you want to disable?")
                                        .setCancelable(true)
                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                "YES",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                        int which) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                })

                                        .setNegativeButton(
                                                "NO",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                        int which) {

                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                        toogledProgrammatically = true;
                                                        sw_enableDisable.toggle();
                                                    }
                                                });

                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So whenever the user clicks on `No` of the `AlertDialog`, you're supposed to toggle the switch again by using

```
sw_enableDisable.toggle();
```

But this would in turn call `onCheckedChanged()` and then it'd be cycle all over again. So to handle that, maintain a boolean `toogledProgrammatically` and set it to `true` whenever you're toggling it in the code. And then when the `onCheckedChanged()` is called, just check if it was toggled programmatically or not. If yes, then don't do anything, else show the alert.

```
if (toogledProgrammatically) {
                            toogledProgrammatically = false;
                        } else {
                            if (isChecked)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onClick:

```
switch.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener(){
    Here_is_createing_of_dialog...
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
    getString("YES"),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        switch.setChecked(true);
    })
});
```

Comment: This wont work because `switch.setChecked(true);` will again call onCheckedChange

Comment: Yes, but i told that user should use only onClick without onChackedChange. In begin of onClick method you can add checking of switch status if(switch.isChecked())

Comment: **This is better and less confusing than using the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`** method since there is a lot of maintenance programmatically. You explicitly have to create a flag that defines if the call is made programmatically because, it creates a loop.

Comment: less confusing yes, but this doesn't work when the user slides the switch instead of clicking it.